# Search and replace in multiple files using vim

Tags: unix, vim

Is it possible to apply the same search and replace in multiple files in `vim`? I'll give an example below.

I have multiple .txt files — `sad1.txt` until `sad5.txt`. To open them, I'll use `vim sad*` and it opened already. Now inside the 5 txt files they have similar word like **happy999**; I would like to change it to **happy111**. I am currently using this code:

```
argdo %s/happy999/happy111/gc | wq!
```

Eventually only the `sad1.txt` is changed. What should I do to run one script in the 5 txt files?

Comment: Are you using `vi` or `vim`?  If you type just `vi`, does it display the `vim` banner message?  The `wq!` may be causing your trouble.  I'd use `:set aw` (auto-write) before running that.  See `:help argdo` if you're using `vim`, which you must be since it is documented as an extension over plain `vi`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know of the existence of `argdo`.

Comment: You can make use of a mapping as well. :map <F12> :%s/source/target/g<CR>:w!<CR>:next<CR>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
:set aw
:argdo %s/happy999/happy111/g
```

The first line sets auto-write mode, so when you switch between files, `vim` will write the file if it has changed.

The second line does your global search and replace.

Note that it doesn't use `wq!` since that exits.  If you don't want to use auto-write, then you could use:

```
:argdo %s/happy999/happy111/g | w
```

This avoids terminating `vim` at the end of editing the first file.

Also consider looking on [`vi` and `vim`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for answers to questions about `vi` and `vim`.

Comment: I was always afraid of `argdo` without a `[range]`.  I've learned something useful, thanks.

Comment: Hello Jonathan. It works. Thank you. follow up question.  I would like to ask. if there is a possible to write and save?  also do I need to set aw everytime?

Comment: You would set `aw` once per vim session, usually.  I don't understand what you mean by 'write and save'; please clarify.

Comment: :argdo %s/happy999/happy111/g | w this worked for all files . but if i put it | wq! . only the first file is changed.

Comment: What would you expect it to do?  The q is for 'quit'; if vim doesn't exit, it is certainly not unreasonable for the q to interrupt the processing.

Answer (score 1):

That is a task for `sed -i` (`-i` for "in place", works only with GNU sed).  Yet, if you really want to use `vim` or you do need the `/c` to confirm the replace, you can do it in two ways:

With some help from the shell:

```
for i in sad*.txt; do
    vim -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':wq' "$i"
done
```

(the `/c` will still work, and vim will ask for each confirmation)

Or with pure VIM

```
vim -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':w' -c ':n' \
    -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':w' -c ':n' \
    -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':w' -c ':n' \
    -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':w' -c ':n' \
    -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc' -c ':wq' sad*.txt
```

(In my humble opinion this last one looks horrible and repetitive and has no real advantages over the shell `for`, but it shows that pure `vim` can do it)

Comment: `vim`'s `argdo` command looks like it should help — it does a useful job, without repeated typing.

Comment: The `colon` should not be there in `vim -c ':%s/happy999/happy111/gc` and the following code

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, `argdo` is great, but to type that much boilerplate becomes quite annoying over the time. 
Give a try to [far.vim](https://github.com/brooth/far.vim). It's such a tool that provide many IDEs.

[image]

Comment: I don't really see the usefulness of this. You type `fardo` instead of `argdo`? Same number of letters and not as intuitive. All good coders should be able to use Vim blindfolded anyway because they can touch type and know where all their code is. I'm sticking to `vim`, `tmux` and `bash`, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need/want to be prompted for confirmation on each search and replace, use the following command, after opening your files with `vim sad*`:

`:argdo %s/happy999/happy111/g | update`

You can find more info by looking at the documentation for `argdo` in vim (`:h argdo`) or here:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers